# JSON Deserialize with empty field c#

Tags: c#, json, deserialization, json-deserialization

I'm testing some api calls in c# and getting the following JSON response:

```
{
  "message": "The request is invalid. Model validation failed.",
  "validationErrors": {
    "": {
      "reasons": [
        "A customer must be added to the order before it can be placed."
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I want to map this response to a class with a JSON Deserializer and I have no control over how the response is formed. How do I handle that empty field in validationErrors so that I can still access the reasons list in my object?

Note: when I ran it through json2csharp it gave this not too useful mapping for that field within the validationErrors class.

```
public __invalid_type__ __invalid_name__ {get;set;}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Deserialize to a `Dictionary<string, ValidationError>`:

```
public class ValidationError
{
    public List<string> reasons { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public string message { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, ValidationError> validationErrors { get; set; }
}
```

This will work out-of-the-box with [javascriptserializer](/questions/tagged/javascriptserializer) and [json.net](/questions/tagged/json.net).  If you are using [`DataContractJsonSerializer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer.aspx) (tagged as  [datacontractjsonserialize](/questions/tagged/datacontractjsonserialize)) you will need to set [`DataContractJsonSerializer.UseSimpleDictionaryFormat = true`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer.usesimpledictionaryformat.aspx) (.Net 4.5 and above only).

Comment: Worked! Accessing a value with an empty key isn't my favorite thing in the world, but the api devs are at fault for that, not you.

Answer (score 3):

If you have your own class which you're trying to deserealization, you can try to use [Newtonsoft-Json](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) to configure your Json property names by `JsonPropertyAttribute` and set it like:

```
public class YourModel
{
    [JsonProperty(name = "")
    public ValidationErrors { get; set; }
}
```

More examples here - [link](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/serializationattributes.htm)

Or, you can deserealize your property as a `Dictionary<string, YourErrorObject>` and use the first one item for access to errors.